# What is the rationale behind particular reserved characters in a URL?

Tags: language-agnostic

I notice these characters are all illegal

```
#%<>?\/*+|:"
```

I notice these are encoded (%NN where NN is the hex value) but can be replace without problem

```
$,;=& @
```

(note the space which is typically encoded as `+` (but may be %20))

`#%?/+` i understand. But whats do the following characters do? `<>\*|":`

Note: I understand what `:` does in the domain part (its the port) as @ is a login but after the first / why is : illegal? (@ isnt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[RFC 2396 (Uniform Resource Identifiers URI: Generic Syntax)](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) says:

> Many URI include components consisting of or delimited by, certain
>   special characters.  These characters are called "reserved", since
>   their usage within the URI component is limited to their reserved
>   purpose.

```
reserved    = ";" | "/" | "?" | ":" | "@" | "&" | "=" | "+" |
              "$" | ","
```

> 2.4.3. Excluded US-ASCII Characters
>
> The angle-bracket "<" and ">" and double-quote (") characters are
>   excluded because they are often used as the delimiters around URI in
>   text documents and protocol fields.  The character "#" is excluded
>   because it is used to delimit a URI from a fragment identifier in URI
>   references (Section 4). The percent character "%" is excluded because
>   it is used for the encoding of escaped characters.

```
delims      = "<" | ">" | "#" | "%" | <">
```

> Other characters are excluded because gateways and other transport
>   agents are known to sometimes modify such characters, or they are
>   used as delimiters.

```
unwise      = "{" | "}" | "|" | "\" | "^" | "[" | "]" | "`"
```

I think that covers all that you mentioned. The star "`*`" is not reserved and may be used. Paste this in a browser: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/*

Comment: hmm, when i put `*` on my page i get a 'Bad Request' error. It must be an asp.net thing

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this, but could those be reserved so that if you try typing in URLs into a shell environment, the URL isn't split up into different pieces unnecessarily?  For example, imagine I try executing

```
curl http://www.stackoverflow.com/this>that > myFile.txt
```

This might trip up the command prompt by having it try to get the incorrect URL `http://www.stackoverflow.com/this`, then writing it to a file called `that`, and then tripping up the interpreter when it hits the second `>`.  This explanation does account for all of the characters you listed (they all mean something in a shell environment), but it's just my first guess as to why it could be.